# iCloud GameKit 40 request / second limit questions

Tags: icloud, gamekit

I'll be straightforward:

1. What does it count as a "request" ? in some posts I've read a request is a "fetch", but on some others says 1 same operation of saving/updating might occur into several "requests".
2. What does it mean the system "throttles" your requests? I've heard if you reach the limit of 40 req / second, the system "throttles" your requests.... what does exactly mean this? and which criteria does it use? I'm guessing if you get a peak for whatever reason of lets say 80 req/second but after that you go back to your average 20/second the system won't charge you? if it's that, which criteria does it use?
3. If for any reason you need more requests per second... you simply have to pay the penalty? or is there any way around it?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think I found the key of the matter.

The scarce documentation says you have 40 requests/second per database. So if you are using private databases foreach user that means each user has 40 request/second .
This changes if you are using public database where all have access of course.

Someone please correct me if I'm wrong.

Thanks